# what does the phrase "no zero divisors mod 13" mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across this while trying to work a problem :

[image]

What is a "zero divisor" and how are they able to use zero product property as if it is an algebraic equation ?  Highly appreciate any help ! thanks!

Comment: If you google zero divisor, four of the first five results are great answers to this question. It's also likely that your book defines a zero divisor, and/or has it in its index.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I am not satisfied with google results as they define it using abstract algebra terminology and I am in number theory at the moment

Answer (score 4):

A zero divisor modulo $m$ is any nonzero residue class $x$ such that there exists another nonzero residue class $y$ with $xy$ the zero residue class.

In symbols: $x \not\equiv 0\ (\text{mod } m)$ and $y \not\equiv 0\ (\text{mod } m)$ but $xy \equiv 0\ (\text{mod } m)$.

Because $p$ is prime, for any integers $a,b$ you have that if $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. This translates precisely into the statement in question.

Comment: Ahh I missed that $p|ab \implies  p|a ~or~  p|b$ nice :) is there a number theoretic definition for "zero divisor" ? because I got 0 matches when I searched for it in my textbook(David M Burton 6th edition). Thank you so much :)

Comment: @rsadhvika: I am confused by your question because my first sentence is the number-theoretic definition of a zero divisor.

Comment: Oh it seems they are not covering this cool topic in our course :/ Even my textbook has no mention of "zero divisor" so I thought I will be learning it in abstract algebra but guess I need to learn it on my own

Answer (score 2):

well for example $z_{13}= \left \{ {\color{Magenta} 0},1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 \right \}$
there is no nonzero  $a,b \in z_{13}$ s.t $ab=0 \bmod 13$ , how ever this is the same for any $z_{p}=\left \{ {\color{Magenta} 0},1,2,...,p-1 \right \}$ such that $p$ is prime , there is no nonzero  $a,b \in z_{p}$ s.t $ab=0 \bmod p$. (no zero divisor )

now take other example (to make it clear when its not prime ):-

$z_{24}= \left \{ {\color{Magenta} 0},1,2,3...,23 \right \}$

$2\times 12 =0 \bmod 24$

$3\times 8 =0 \bmod 24$

$4\times 6 =0 \bmod 24$

so zero divisors are $\left \{2,3,4,6,8,12 \right \}$ .

now for your question , since there is no zero divisors in modulo 13 ( 13 is prime )
then for any $ab=0 \bmod 13\rightarrow $ $a=0 \bmod 13$  or $ b=0 \bmod 13 $

let me know if you dint get it or if u still need help :)

PS:- the existence of zero divisors depends on the ring group itself this is why its abstract algebra and not number theory as u can see in this example we used module thats my number theory might be involved but there is many other ring groups might have zero divisors (if u worked on matrices or other operations ) then it would be diffrent .